# Get error "login.live.com page can’t be found" when invoking Azure Ad as external IDP in IdentitySrever4

Tags: azure-active-directory, identityserver4

I try to follow [this tutorial](https://www.ashleyhollis.com/how-to-configure-azure-active-directory-with-identityserver4) to add Azure Ad as another external IDP for my IdentityServer4 service (I have gotten Windows and Google working already). I can get the "Azure Ad" button displayed on my IdentityServer login page now, but when I click on it, I get the following error returned:

[image]

Here is how I configured Azure Ad in ConfigureServices of my Startup class. I also tried replacing "aad" with "oidc", which is what I used and worked in Google, but no difference here.

[image]

and here is how my Azure Ad account configuration looks like. The colors match up with above indicating the values I use in my code:

[image]

Can someone tell me what I may be doing wrong here?

Comment: You should use https://login.microsoftonline.com as the authority. Check the updated  [docs](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-active-directory-identity/simplifying-our-azure-ad-authentication-flows/ba-p/243928)

Comment: Thanks @a_e! I replaced login.windows.net with login.microsoftonline.com in my options.Authority, but it made no difference. I am still getting the same error. BTW, I have left the Directory (tenant) ID part unchanged in the uri.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initially please  try by deleting history in the browser and  use `"login.microsoftonline.com/<tenantId>/v2.0/"` as authority string.
And `options.CallbackPath = "/signin-oidc";`  `options.ResponseType = "code id_token";`

***NOTE :*** ***The identity platform which is used by Microsoft has a character limit for links. This  type of error will appear if the authorization request or link is longer than the said limit,.***

Protocols like  OpenID Connect, allow `state` as a parameter in the authorization  request, and the identity provider will return that state in the  response as you can find that in  error page you provided .
Because of which the request URL becomes large as sometimes  the state parameter is long.(which might be the possible case here)

Try to call the **`AddOidcStateDataFormatterCache`** extension method on the IServiceCollection in startup class which uses the distributed cache in the backend like:

```
services.AddIdentityServer()
    .AddDeveloperSigningCredential()
    .AddInMemoryIdentityResources(Config.GetIdentityResources())
    .AddInMemoryApiResources(Config.GetApiResources())
    .AddInMemoryClients(Config.GetClients())
    .AddTestUsers(Config.GetUsers());

 services.AddAuthentication()
            .AddOpenIdConnect("aad", "Azure AD", options =>
            {
                // ...
            })
```

you can write the way as below  :

```
services.AddOidcStateDataFormatterCache(); //Add this line

    services.AddAuthentication()
        .AddOpenIdConnect("aad", "Azure AD", options =>
        {
            // ...
        })
```

You may check these similar **References**  for more details :

[Sign-in with External Identity Providers — IdentityServer4 1.0.0 documentation](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/release/topics/signin_external_providers.html?highlight=StateFormatter#state-url-length-and-isecuredataformat)

(Or)

See section :  **22.4 Handling the callback and signing in** the user in [IdentityServer4 Documentation](https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/_/downloads/en/aspnetcore2/pdf/)

At least check for dns or firewall issues .

Comment: Thanks! I think AddOidcStateDataFormatterCache did it. The reason why I say I think, is that I am now getting a different error - "The reply URL specified in the request does not match the reply URLs configured for the application: '...'". I believe that's caused by the callback uri mismatch. I have been having a hard time to figure out how to configure that uri on Azure Ad site... But that's a different issue. Thanks again!